# Error when trying to install mysql support for rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Ruby version : 1.8.7 (2013-06-27 patchlevel 374) [x86_64-linux]
Rails version : 2.3.5
OS: Cloud Linux 64 bit

I am trying to install mysql gem inorder to get support rails, the command is as follows,

```
gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config
```

am getting the following error,

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby extconf.rb --with-mysql-                                config=/usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config
extconf.rb:5: command not found: /usr/lib64/mysql/mysql_config --cflags
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration  options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p374/bin/ruby
    --with-mysql-config


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/mysql-2.9.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p374/gems/mysql-2.9.1/ext/mysql_api/gem_make.out
```

I even tried looking for mkmf.log, but cannot find it.
I am trying to implement a RoR project, which already ran in Cent OS 5.9 64bit. This RoR is designed to be run in the above versions of Ruby & Rails, upgrading will create issues. Please help and direct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are missing dev parts of libraries.
Do you have libmysqlclient installed? 
What is the output of the locate command for the config file?

```
locate mysql_config
```

Comment: No, I haven't installed any libmysqlclient, if so how do I do it, and what version of it? 
If I run 'locate mysql_config', I get the following response
'locate: can not stat () `/var/lib/mlocate/mlocate.db': No such file or directory'

Comment: update over all comment, ran `updatedb`, to remove the error.
Now I get a lot mysql_client locations don't know which one to use

Comment: FINAL UPDATE - finally i found the mysql_client location at `/usr/bin/mysql_config`. Now things are running fine, will keep updated.